Azure functions not working inside docker
I created one azure function using the following command:
func init --worker-runtime python --docker
func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger"

Then I created a docker image using the following dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

The simple azure function is working locally using func start and also working inside docker image.
But after that I used another application using azure function where I imported various libraries. That application is working fine locally using func start but it is not working inside docker image.
At http://localhost:8080/api/HttpExample, I got error that no web page found and in the console I got a warning that no job functions found.
This is the code which I used:
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging
from model import predict

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpExample", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

def HttpExample(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        name=predict(name)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"{name}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in "
             "the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

Inside model.py file I imported various libraries of llama index
This is my requirements.txt file:
azure-core
azure-functions
azure-identity
llama-index
llama-index-embeddings-azure-openai
llama-index-llms-azure-openai
llama-index-readers-file
llama-index-vector-stores-chroma
pypdf

What things need to be done to make the azure function work inside docker image?

Please provide the libraries you have imported.

I imported various libraries of llama index.For example:
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

Please share your code.

I edited my question and added my code

Provide your requirements.txt as well.

I added the requirements.txt after editing

Thanks for providing the code. Can you share Model.py?


Build the docker image again and run the function.

I have created a Python Azure Function and used your code to run using docker image.

I have used below sample code in model.py:

from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

def predict(input):
    # prediction code
    prediction= "Hello "+input
    return prediction

function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
from model import predict

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpExample", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

def HttpExample(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        name=predict(name)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"{name}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}


Build the docker image of the Azure function:

C:\Users\uname\dotnetfn\pyfn> docker build -t pravallikaXXXX/dockerpyfn .

[+] Building 7.5s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 466B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11                                          0.7s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 59B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11@sha256:5d3278f29f0XXXX8b  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                               6.5s
 => => transferring context: 2.71MB                                                                                             5.8s
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY requirements.txt /                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] COPY . /home/site/wwwroot                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f98587280a9d53f3a4493dfa7ffdb3148b32081d8a5a180a63c7842472eed302                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/pravallikaXXXX/dockerpyfn   


Running the docker image of Azure function:

docker run -p 8080:80 <Image_name>


Response:



Sample function is working for me also. but inside model.py, the function is not sample. Due to some difficulty I am not able to share that code.And that code is working fine locally but not working in docker image

Did you try with a new image?

Yes I tried but that also not working

If you can share your Model.py, I will run and test it. As of now, I have tried with my own Model.py code.
